# Finding Radius of a Circle that Contains All the Points in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random, methods

I have the following program to write:

> Write a program that performs the following:
>   1. Declare an array of size 20 of type XYPoint.
>   2. Fill the array with 20 random points. The x- and y-coordinates should contain values between -1000 and 1000
>   3. Print the contents of the array to the screen.
>   4. Calculate the radius of the smallest circle, centered at the origin, that will enclose all of the points. This must be done after
>   ALL of the points have been create.
>   5. Print the radius.

This is my program so far:

```
import net.apcs.classes.XYPoint;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EncloseInCircle {
    public static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XYPoint a[];
        a = new XYPoint[20];
        XYPoint random;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int x = (rand.nextInt(1001) + 10000);
            int y = (rand.nextInt(1001) + 10000);
            random = new XYPoint(x, y);

            a[i] = random;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to find the radius of a circle that encloses all the random points in my array... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: posting homework is not a good use of this site

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a homework question. To solve problems like these, I find it easy to first solve the problem for a trivial case, i.e. 1 point, and start working from there.

So, for example, in the trivial case of 1 point, how would you find a radius of a circle (centered at (0,0)), that would encompass this point? That should be straightforward. Now about the case for 2 points? 3?

The algorithm should reveal itself as you work through higher order cases.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

A hint without giving the actual code, because you need to learn from the exercise and code it yourself.

A circle that encompasses the furthest point from the origin will encompass all the other points which are closer to the origin.

Consider looping through all your points and keeping a note of the highest distance from the origin. You will need to use a simple formula to calculate the distance from the origin for each point. This can be considered a radius of a circle.

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Since I like recursion.

Assuming I had solved the problem for `n-1` and I am attempting to solve it for `n` points:

I would just calculate if the solution (a circle) for the first n-1 points contains the nth point.  It either does or does not and what you should do should be obvious in each case.  The solution for the base case n=1 should also be obvious.

I just took https://stackoverflow.com/a/35281932/348975's hint and reversed it.